# flashplayer_32_sa: SecurityError: Error #2028: Local-with-filesystem SWF file

Tags: flash, swfobject

When trying to run SWF "[S] Past Karkat: Wake up." through flashplayer_32_sa, a window pops up with the title "An ActionScript error occurred" and the following text:

```
SecurityError: Error #2028: Local-with-filesystem SWF file file:///C|/Users/spani/Downloads/02791%20%281%29.swf cannot access Internet URL https://www.mspaintadventures.ru/storyfiles/hs2/songs/alterniaboundsongs/Crustacean.mp3.
    at flash.media::Sound/_load()
    at flash.media::Sound/load()
    at flash.media::Sound()
    at Alterniabound_fla::MainTimeline/frame1()[C:\Users\RadRussianRus\Documents\02791\Alterniabound_fla\MainTimeline.as:351]
```

After that, the file does not run.

I tried reinstalling the file and i tried to install the English version of the file and got a slightly different error text:

```
SecurityError: Error #2028: Local-with-filesystem SWF file file:///C|/Users/spani/Downloads/%5BS%5D%20Past%20Karkat%20Wake%20up..swf cannot access Internet URL http://www.mspaintadventures.com/storyfiles/hs2/songs/alterniaboundsongs/Crustacean.mp3.
    at flash.media::Sound/_load()
    at flash.media::Sound/load()
    at flash.media::Sound()
    at Alterniabound_fla::MainTimeline/frame1()
```

(I have zero programming knowledge plz help)

Comment: You are facing the Flash local security. When you build an SWF, you to state, how this SWF behaves if run through the local Flash Player Projector: it is either local-with-filesystem (can access local files only) or local-with-network (can access network only) and cannot have both at the same time. The SWF in question was (most probably) published for web, where this parameter does not matter. In a nutshell, this SWF was not supposed to run as you want it to, so it does not.